# Detect highlighted text in an html container

Tags: html, reactjs

How can I detect the text being highlighted by the user within a non input/textarea element? I am rendering an array of characters within a span, and would like to be able to detect which elements are being highlighted by the user. However, I cannot see any ref properties that would enable me to do this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sound-rk3mf

```
import React from "react";

const values = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

const textRef = React.createRef();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div ref = {textRef}>
      {values.map(val => <var> {val} </var>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a click event to get the element got highlighted:

```js
import React from "react";

const values = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const textRef = React.createRef();

export default function App() {
  // bind this event to the element
  const checkText = e => {
    console.log(`Hilighted item is: "${e.currentTarget.textContent}".`);
  };
  return (
    <div ref={textRef}>
      {values.map((val, i) => (
        <var key={i} onClick={checkText}> //<-----here is the bound event
          {" "}{val}{" "}
        </var>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox updated.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sad-frog-7pp0n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)